# HTML: layout text and image together

Tags: html, css

I need to have text and image so that they are vertically aligned together. Specifically image should be vertically positioned at the middle of the text. What's the best way to do that?

One constraint: the content of my **`<img>`** tag is retrieved from external source and it would be great if I could leave **`<img>`** tag unchanged (no attributes added).

Sample:

```
<div>Some text <img src="http://somewhere.com/someimage.png"/></div>
```

Comment: please provide some piece of your code

Answer (score 1):

`img { vertical-align: middle; }`

Might be best to add a `class` or `id` to the `img` or surrounding `div` though as this will affect all `img` tags on the page

Answer (score 0):

div{background:url("http://somewhere.com/someimage.png") 50% 50% no-repeat; line-height:1.5em; text-align:center}

should do it. depending on font-size